# OpenCV Grabbing the image skips current (or next) frame

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I've recently realised that all of my output videos are twice as fast as the original, so i made the program print out the current frame and noticed that it was increasing by 2 each time (2,4,6,8...). When I removed the "cap>>currentImage;" it printed 1,2,3,4,...

I just don't understand why this is happening. Is there a mistake in the way I'm printing the frame? Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /// CHANGE INPUT FILE HERE
    Mat currentImage;
    VideoCapture cap("testcut.avi");//"herman.avi"

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
            cout << "Failed to open the input video" << endl;
            exit(5);}

    for(;;){
        cap>>currentImage;
        if (!cap.grab())
        {
            cout << "\n End of video, looping" << endl;
            cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0);
        }
    waitKey(80);
    cout<<"frame number=         "<<cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because you first grab and read the frame with the [>> operator](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) and then you grab another one with the `cap.grab()`. Seems like the classic problem of not reading the docs. :)

Comment: @DanMašek Oh great! So would using only the if (!cap.grab()) loop work with calling it. And then put "Mat currentImage = cap" after the loop. That seems very possible. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just use [`bool VideoCapture::read(Mat& image)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) -- that will try to grab and retrieve the frame, and return a boolean signifying whether it succeeded or not.